# How to make 3D effect to a box container and how to choose colors?

Tags: css

How do I make the design of this box better? Making its header and footer 3D, better choice colors, ...

I've tried this:

[image]

Here is its related code:

```
.boxfooter {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fbfcfa;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  color:#8EA2AA;
}
.boxheader{
  margin:6px 0 0 0;
  font-size:20px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fbfcfa;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  padding:4px;
}
.box {
  background-color:#fbfcfa;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  display: block;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the demo below.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtS6r/)

I used the [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to have this effect.

Also if you want to have effect, wrap them up then add this code to the wrapper.

```
.box-wrapper {
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

For engraved effect you can try the css below.

```
.box-wrapper {
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

To adjust the lightness/darkness of the shadow. Just replace the rgba's `0.5` and chooose a number from the range of `0.1` to `1.0`.

`0.1` - lightest `1.0` - darkest

Comment: Thanks for your response, how do I to make its colors more clear (less dark)?

Comment: Color of the shadow? or the gradient?

Comment: if you want to reduce the darkness, then reduce the last number of the box shadow's rgba ex: `box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`

Comment: have you check [this link?](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) By using this tool you can adjust the gradient's color and then copy paste it to your code afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to stand out more, go for something like a box-shadow.

```
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000000;
```

and as for colours, that's totally up to you, just experiment, and look up [HEX colour codes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm trying to make this less dark, any suggestion, please?

Comment: the shadowing can be made less dark, either by reducing the size of the shadow 'box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;' or by using a lighter colour such as grey, #555555, #666666 up to #999999. Hope it helps.